# navbar-toggler-icon not showing how can i fix it?

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

toggler-icon is functional but its not showing itself. Has anyone run into this error with [react-getboostrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) ? i think i might be missing some extra bit of info, but because of johari's window - i dont know what i dont know.

```
<Navbar  collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Container>

        <Navbar.Brand href="/"> Title</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#">page</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#">page</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#">page</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
          <Nav className="nav-link">
            {user ? (
            <div className='ml-4 dropdown d-inline'>
              <Nav.Link to ='#!'className='btn dropdown-toggle text-white' type='button' id='dropDownMenuButton'
              data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>
                <figure className='avatar avatar-nav'>
                    <img src={user.avatar && user.avatar.url}
                    alt ={user && user.name}
                    className = 'rounded-circle'/>
                </figure>
                <span>{user && user.name}</span>
                </Nav.Link>
                <div className='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropDownMenuButton'>
                  {user && user?.role !== 'admin'?(
                    <NavDropdown.Item className='dropdown-item' href='#'> Content</NavDropdown.Item>
                  ):(
                    <>
                    <NavDropdown.Item className='dropdown-item' href='#'> page</NavDropdown.Item>
                    <NavDropdown.Item className='dropdown-item' href='#'> page</NavDropdown.Item></>
                  )}
                  <NavDropdown.Item className='dropdown-item' href='/#'> page</NavDropdown.Item>

                  <NavDropdown.Item className='dropdown-item text-danger' href = '#' onClick={logoutHandler}>
                      Logout
                  </NavDropdown.Item>

                </div>
            </div>

            ):!loading && <Nav.Link  href="#" > Login</Nav.Link> }



            {/* <Nav.Link href="#" >Login</Nav.Link> */}
            {/* <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#">


            </Nav.Link> */}
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
```